# Netbeans: Apply macro to muliple lines?

Tags: netbeans, ide, macros, editor, text-editor

Currently using this to apply `<li>` `</li>` to highlighted text.

`cut-to-clipboard "<li>" paste-from-clipboard "</li>"`

I was wondering if it's possible to apply this macro to multiple lines of text?

E.g., if these whole 4 line of text is highlight by mouse then macro is applied:

```
Hello
World
Hello
World
```

it becomes:

```
<li>Hello</li>
<li>World</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>World</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly easy to do with find and replace.

1. Select the lines to replace.
2. Choose Edit -> Replace from menu or use `<CNTRL>-H` key.
3. Set the toggle-button for Regular Expression if it is not already set.
4. In the `Find What:` field put `(.*)\n`
5. In the  `Replace With:` field put `<li>$1</li>\n`
6. Click the `Replace All` button.

Unfortunately as far as I know, there is no good way to make this a macro. If you try to record this as a macro it doesn't work because it does not record anything to move from the Find What to Replace With field.